# Facebook graph api people search using app access token only?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, token

Is it possible to do a Graph API search without requiring the user to login? (App token only?)

ie: I want my user to be able search for Facebook Users from my website without requiring them to allow access with my application. I simply want my web page to return a list of matching names.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can't do that.
Allways you need at least an user token, so after he/she authenticate you can search "impersonating" that user,